# Want to show data from two different tables in two different datagridviews in a form in c#

Tags: c#, database, datagridview

I have two different queries for two different tables I want to show the result in two datagridviews on a form

```
string query1 = string.Format("select * from Flat where [Flat_No.]='{0}'",flat.Text);
string query2 = string.Format("select * from 1");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query1, con);
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query2, con1);

dataview frm1 = new dataview(query1,query2); //the form where data is to be displayed

// on form dataview I have two DataGridViews
public dataview(string a,string b)
{
        InitializeComponent();

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Class1.getConnectionString);
        //connection name

        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(a , con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        da.Fill(ds, "ss");

        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["ss"];
        con.Close();

        SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(Class1.getConnectionString);
        //connection name for query1

        con1.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(b, con1);
        cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);

        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();

        da.Fill(ds1, "aa");

        dataGridView2.DataSource = ds1.Tables["aa"];
        con1.Close();
   }
}
```

but the above code is showing data from query 1 in both the datagridviews. plz help me out how can I solve this problem? If there in another way let me know it also. I have also tried to merge both the queries using "+" sign but it also didn't proved helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `da1.Fill` instead of `da.fill`. You're using the `da` `DataAdapter` for filling both `Datasets`

<strike>da.Fill(ds1, "aa");</strike>

```
da1.Fill(ds1, "aa");
```